# CSVwriter acts strange with large lists

Tags: python, csv

I have been using python to write a large number of data to a CSV file.
I use the following code:

```
for elem in element:
   csvfile.writerow(elem)
```

The code iterates about 10,000 times trough this, as it should because the for loop gets used for every element in a large list.
simple enough, right?
but when elem are extremely large lists, think +5,000 elements or more the csvwriter acts strange.
Normally I expect the results to look like this:

```
"line 1, line 1, line 1 line 1..."
"line 2, line 2, line 2,..."
```

but what I get with extremely large values is:

```
"line 1, line 1,
line 1, line 1..."
"line 2, line 2,
line 2, line 2..."
```

It's never supposed to start a new line unless it's a new iteration...
It works fine with small data samples.
Also in notepad++ it shows up is different lines...
Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT

For people asking: 
This is the actual code:

top_words = a list of 10.000 most common words

```
for text, cat in texts:
    words = wordpunct_tokenize(text)
    word_c=len(words)
    c = Counter()
    c.update(word for word in words if word in top_words)
    word_freq = [c.get(word,0) for word in top_words]
    word_freq = ','.join(map(str, word_freq))
    csvfile.writerow((word_freq, cat))
```

Comment: are you sure thats not just your text editor wrapping long lines for you?

Comment: how so? like for elem.strip() in elem?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it shows up the same way in excel, notepad++ and VIM, unless it is a standard way of wrapping, it can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Can you show actual runnable code and sample data (hopefully trivial sample data, like `elem = range(6000)`) that reproduces this problem? Because either (a) there's unescaped newlines in your input data, or (b) there's something silly in your actual code, or (c) there's a bug in Python (possibly fixed in a later version, so please give your version number).

Comment: Also, the fact that each entire row is enclosed in a single pair of quotes implies that either you're doing something wrong, or you have no reason to use CSV in the first place, because you only have one column. Is that accurate for your real data?

Comment: I just did a quick test with Python 2.7.2, writing rows lines each consisting of 100K copies of the number 0, and I ended up with only 100 lines, so… if this is a bug in Python or the `csv` module, it's presumably either fixed before 2.7.2, or Windows-specific…

Comment: I edited my code.
I am using 2.7.3 because this version is supported by NLTK. 
And every line is enclosed by quotes, and no I do not know why.